# Splitting string on multiple spaces in java

Tags: java, string, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)

I need help while parsing a text file. 
The text file contains data like

```
This is     different type   of file.
Can not split  it    using ' '(white space)
```

My problem is spaces between words are not similar. Sometimes there is single space and sometimes multiple spaces are given.

I need to split the string in such a way that I will get only words, not spaces.

Comment: not duplicate as this question is for splitting with variable length white space

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate at all. The "possible duplicate" does not address the corner case of multiple-spaces, which is the main point of the question. For reference, this question is also the first result on google when you search for `java string split multiple spaces`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`str.split("\\s+")` would work. The `+` at the end of the regular-expression, would treat multiple spaces the same as a single space. It returns an array of strings (`String[]`) without any `" "` results.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`Quantifiers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) to specify the number of spaces you want to split on: -

```
    `+` - Represents 1 or more
    `*` - Represents 0 or more
    `?` - Represents 0 or 1
`{n,m}` - Represents n to m
```

So, `\\s+` will split your string on `one or more` spaces

```
String[] words = yourString.split("\\s+");
```

Also, if you want to specify some specific numbers you can give your range between `{}`:

```
yourString.split("\\s{3,6}"); // Split String on 3 to 6 spaces
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a regular expression.

```
String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use regex pattern

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s="This is     different type   of file.";
    String s1[]=s.split("[ ]+");
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s1[i]);
    }
}
```

output

```
This
is
different
type
of
file.
```

Comment: Your solution only splits by blanks, not by any other whitespace characters such as `\t\n\x0B\f\r`. Use the character class `\s` (any whitespace character) instead, as described by the others. `String[] words = yourString.split("\\s+"); `

Answer (score 0):

you can use
replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) method of String class to replace the multiple spaces with space and then you can use split method.

Answer (score 0):

```
String spliter="\\s+";
String[] temp;
temp=mystring.split(spliter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you another method to tockenize your string if you dont want to use the split method.Here is the method

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    String str="This is     different type   of file.Can not split  it    using ' '(white space)";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, " "); 
    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
 }
```

Comment: And why wouldn't he want to use the split method, given that it is a better way to go than `StringTokenizer`? Please stop using `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: Rohit can u pls illustrate why split is better than StringTokenizer

Comment: You can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/splitting_tokenisation_performance.shtml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965767/performance-of-stringtokenizer-class-vs-split-method-in-java