# How to make my code more time-efficient

Tags: java, performance

I am submitting the following code to an online judge.
**Input Specification**
The data provided by Bill and Ted has the following format: The first line consists of the number p of parties followed by the number g of guesses (with 1 ≤ p ≤ 50 and 1 ≤ g ≤ 10000). Then follow p lines, each line consisting of a unique party name of length ≤ 20 (only containing letters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9) and the achieved vote percentage of this party with one digit after the decimal point. After the parties follow g lines, each consisting of a guess. A guess has the form P1 + P2 + ... + Pk COMP n, where P1 to Pk are party names, COMP is one of the comparison operators <, >, <=, >= or = and n is an integer between 0 and 100, inclusively. Each party name occurs at most once in each guess.

**Output Specification**
For each guess, sum up the vote percentages of the parties and compare them with the specified integer n. Then, print a line stating whether the guess was correct. See the sample output for details.

but whatever i do it always gives me time limit exceeded ...and here is my final code,

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String Ints =  br.readLine();
    String Guess;
    String [] Ints_array = Ints.split("[ ]+");
    int p = Integer.parseInt(Ints_array[0]);
    int g = Integer.parseInt(Ints_array[1]);
    HashMap<String, Float> Parties = new HashMap<String, Float>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < p ; i++) {
        String temp = br.readLine();
        String [] temp_array = temp.split("[ ]+");
        Parties.put(temp_array[0],Float.parseFloat(temp_array[1]));
    }

    for(int j = 0 ; j < g ; j++) {
        Guess = br.readLine();
        float actual = 0;
          String [] temp = Guess.split("[ ]+");

        if(Guess.contains("+"))
        {

            for(int i = 0 ; i < temp.length-2 ; i++)
            {
                if(!temp[i].contains("+"))
                actual+= Parties.get(temp[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            actual=Parties.get(temp[0]);
        }

        float guess = Float.parseFloat(temp[temp.length-1]);

                if( temp[temp.length-2].contains(">"))
               {
                   if(temp[temp.length-2].contains("="))
                   {
                       if(actual >= guess)
                         System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was correct."); 
                    else
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was incorrect.");  
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    if(actual > guess)
                       System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was correct."); 
                    else
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was incorrect."); 
                     }
               } 

                  else if( temp[temp.length-2].equals("<"))
               {
                   if(temp[temp.length-2].contains("="))
                   {
                       if(actual <= guess)
                         System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was correct."); 
                    else
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was incorrect.");  
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    if(actual < guess)
                       System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was correct."); 
                    else
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was incorrect."); 
                     }  
               } 

                    else if( temp[temp.length-2].equals("="))
               {
                    if(actual == guess)
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was correct."); 
                    else
                        System.out.println("Guess #"+(j+1)+" was incorrect.");  
               } 
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write a part of the answer, because I think that it would take a good search to have a complete answer.

- Try to use Set in place of Arrays, because the function contains would be faster.
- Raw String split is not the faster way to make a split. Stack Overflow question *[Performance of StringTokenizer class vs. split method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965767)* is a comparison of splitting methods.

Hope this would help.