# How do I return an array of words given an input sentence (string)?

Tags: java, methods

How do I create a method that takes a string as an argument, and returns the array whose elements are the words in the string.

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
// split takes some string as the argument, and returns the array
// whose elements are the words in the string
public static String[] split (String s)
{
    // determine the number of words
    java.util.Scanner t = new java.util.Scanner (s);
    int countWords = 0;
    String w;
    while (t.hasNext ())
    {
        w = t.next ();
        countWords++;
    }
    // create appropriate array and store the string’s words in it
    // code here
}
```

As you can see, I can just input each word via Scanner. Now I just have to put all the words of the String into an array as the elements. However, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Use the ready `split` method: `str.split("\\s+");`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)** in java to devide your string into words:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
```

And your output `st` whould be an `array` of words.

Take a look at this [**Java StringTokenizer tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/) for further information.

Your code whould look like:

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ");
    int n=st.countTokens();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
       words[i]=st.nextToken();// words is your array of words
    }
```

Comment: Note the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) actually recommends using `split` over this legacy class :)

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus: I will keep it in mind. And Split() seems to be faster too referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965767/performance-of-stringtokenizer-class-vs-split-method-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

As Maroun Maroun commented, you should use the `split(regex)` method from `String`s, but if you want to do this by yourself:

First, declare the array:

```
String[] words = new String[50]; // Since you are using an array you have to declare
                                 // a fixed length.
                                 // To avoid this, you can use an ArrayList 
                                 // (dynamic array) instead.
```

Then, you can fill the array inside the `while` loop:

```
while (t.hasNext()) {
    w = t.next();
    words[countWords] = w;
    countWords++;
}
```

And finally return it:

```
return words;
```

**Note:**

The sentences

```
words[countWords] = w;
countWords++;
```

can be simplified in

```
words[countWords++] = w;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Maroun Maroun said: use the split function or like @chsdk said use StringTokenizer.
If you want to use scanner:

```
public static String[] split(String s)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        l.add(sc.next());
    }

    String[] returnValue = new String[l.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < returnValue.length; ++i)
    {
        returnValue[i] = l.get(i);
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```