# Android/Java Regex to remove extra zeros from sub-strings

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have the following string as input :

```
"2.0,3.00,-4.0,0.00,-0.00,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101"
```

Final output will be like :

```
"2,3,-4,0,0,.03,2.01,.001,-.03,101"
```

**i.e.** all leading and trailing zeros will be removed and both positive/negative zeros will be simply zero.

We can achieve this by split the string first and using Regex for each part. But *my string size is more than 10000*.
 How can we achieve this using `Regex`?

Edit:

**Analysis of Answers:**

I have tested all answers with String `"0.00,-0.00,00.00,-00.00,40.00,-40.00,4.0,-4.0,4.01,-4.01,04.01,-04.01,004.04,-004.04,0004.040,-0004.040,101,.40,-.40,0.40,-0.40"` and answer from ***Wiktor Stribiżew*** passed all the test cases .(see here : https://regex101.com/r/tS8hE3/9 ) Other answers were passed on most of the cases but not all.

Comment: I have only split the string ...and next used regex for each parts separately. But that will not be efficient for large strings . How can I achieve this without split ?

Comment: how about you give this solution a try if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965767/performance-of-stringtokenizer-class-vs-split-method-in-java

Comment: processing chars one by one and collecting them in `StringBuilder` would perform much faster and more space-efficient than regex

Comment: After a fix this gets your output https://regex101.com/r/rQ2rG5/1. Just curious, since you gave stribnetz all the gold, is there any reason to believe your input is all valid numbers? You can parse text to convert it to a number. If its not valid it will throw an exception. Otherwise, this is an exercise in futility, ie. _why trim zero's from a number if its not a number_? If you don't do this, you must validate while you parse, which is what mine did. Take a look at this as an example  of what will happen https://regex101.com/r/aH6gX0/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Updated test case answer

Use the following regex:

```
String rx = "-?0+\\.(0)+\\b|\\.0+\\b|\\b0+(?=\\.\\d*[1-9])|\\b0+(?=[1-9]\\d*\\.)|(\\.\\d*?)0+\\b";
```

And replace with `$1$2`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS8hE3/7).

The regex matches several alternatives and *captures* some parts of the string to later re-insert during replacement:

- `-?0+\.(0)+\b` - matching an optional `-` followed with one or more `0`s followed with a `.` and then *captures* exactly one `0` but matching one or more occurrences (because the `(...)` is placed on the `0` and the `+` is applied to this group); the word boundary at the end requires a non-word character to appear after the last matched `0`. In the replacement, we restore the `0` with `$1` backreference. So, `-00.00` or `00.00` will be replaced with `0`.
- `|` - or...
- `\.0+\b` - a dot followed with one or more zeros before a `,` (since the string is comma-delimited).
- `|` - or...
- `\b0+(?=\.\d*[1-9])` - a word boundary (start of string or a location after `,`) followed with one or more `0`s that are followed by `.` + zero or more digits followed by a non-0 digit (so we remove leading zeros in the integer part that only consists of zeros)
- `|`  - or...
- `\b0+(?=[1-9]\d*\.)` - a word boundary followed by one or more zeros followed by a non-0 digit before a `.` (so, we remove all leading zeros from the integer part that is not equal to `0`).
- `|`  - or...
- `(\.\d*?)0+\b` - capturing a `.`+zero or more digits, but as few as possible, up to the first `0`, and then just matching one or more zeros (up to the end of string or `,`) (so, we get rid of trailing zeros in the decimal part)

## Answer before the test cases update

I suggest a very simple and short regex that does what you need:

```
-0+\.(0)+\b|\.0+\b|\b0+(?=\.\d*[1-9])
```

Replace with `$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS8hE3/2). Short [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/yK7zpn):

```
String re = "-0+\\.(0)+\\b|\\.0+\\b|\\b0+(?=\\.\\d*[1-9])"; 
String str = "2.0,3.00,-4.0,0.00,-0.00,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101,0.001,-0.03";
String expected = "2,3,-4,0,0,.03,2.01,.001,-.03,101,.001,-.03"; 
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(re, "$1").equals(expected)); // TRUE
```

*Explanation*:

- `-0+\.(0)+\b` - a minus followed with one or more `0`s (`0+`) followed with a literal dot (`\.`) followed with one or more zeros (and capturing just the last `0` matched with `(0)+`) followed with a word boundary (location before `,` in this context)
- `|` - or...
- `\.0+\b` - a literal dot (`\.`) followed with one or more zeros followed with a word boundary (location before `,` in this context)
- `|` - or...
- `\b0+(?=\.\d*[1-9])` - a word boundary (location after `,` in this context) followed with one or more zeros that *must be followed with* a literal dot (`\.`), then zero or more digits and then a digit from 1 to 9 range (so that the decimal part is more than `0`).

Comment: @nKaushik: I wonder why you selected as accepted a solution that does not do what is asked for.  Please check my answer.

Comment: @Wktor : I can change the accepted answer :) , also award is still open . Please check your pattern with ".50"

Comment: I see, you have more test cases up your sleeve. So, the update is `-0+\.(0)+\b|\.0+\b|\b0+(?=\.\d*[1-9])|\b0+(?=[1-9]\d*\.)|(\.\d*?)0+\b` to replace with `$1$2`.

Comment: Have you had time to check? I see a lot more people have come up with their suggestion in the meantime :)

Comment: `.002.0` becomes `.2`

Comment: @sln: This is an invalid test case. The numbers are separated with commas and there can be only one decimal separator.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew : sorry for replying late. ur case is failing only for 00.00 , it converts it to 0 .

Comment: Do you mean it must be converted to `0`? Like with [`-?0+\.(0)+\b|\.0+\b|\b0+(?=\.\d*[1-9])|\b0+(?=[1-9]\d*\.)|(\.\d*?)0+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tS8hE3/7)?

Comment: I already updated it with the above regex. I will also add explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted it and awarded the bounty.

Comment: I also added the explanations for each alternation branch. If there is anything unclear, please drop a comment. Thank you for a nice riddle :)

Answer (score 3):

```
\.0+$|^(-)?0+(?=\.)
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1`.if u get empty string or `-` after replacement replace it by `0`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/7

If you want to do on full string use

```
-?0*\.0+\b|\.0+(?=,|$)|(?:^|(?<=,))(-)?0+(?=\.)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/16

Comment: ok..it can be used..but i will have to split the string to substrings and use for all substrings separately. Instead of this, how can i directly check for strings between comma and make the modifications ?

Comment: Test string should be "2.0,3.00,-4.0,0.00,-0.00,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101", not individual elements.

Comment: almost correct , but i will have to traverse the string one more time to replace - with 0. is there any option for this ?

Comment: yes..but "-" and blank spaces ? should we have to traverse the string one more time to replace it with 0 ?

Comment: sorry for removing accepted. ur answer does not work with .50

Comment: .5 i.e. we will remove all extra zeros from a number. ( extra zero means without these zeros also, value of the number will be same)

Comment: :sorry but other answers have much better solution. (i.e. without traversing two times.)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** to cover more cases such as `01.`,`.100`, `01.10`

```
(?<=,|^)(?:[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|\.\B|$))|0+(?=[1-9]))|\.0+\b|\b0+(?=\d*\.\b)|\.\B|(?<=[1-9])0+(?=,|$)
```

This pattern requires more backtracking, thus can get slower on large input. Java String:

```
"(?<=,|^)(?:[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|\\.\\B|$))|0+(?=[1-9]))|\\.0+\\b|\\b0+(?=\\d*\\.\\b)|\\.\\B|(?<=[1-9])0+(?=,|$)"
```

In addition to the previous pattern this one matches

- `(?<=,|^)(?:`...`|0+(?=[1-9]))` add leading zeros preceding `[1-9]`
- `\.0+\b` modified to match period with zeros only before a *word boundary*
- `\b0+(?=\d*\.\b)` match zeros at boundary if period preceded by optional digits [ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `\.\B` matches a period bordering  to a *non word boundary* (eg `.,`)
- `(?<=[1-9])0+(?=,|$)` matches trailing zeros following `[1-9]`

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jF6wJ5/3) or [Regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/9jnh96) (click Java)

---

<sup>Answer before update</sup>
You can also try `replaceAll` this regex with empty.

```
(?<=,|^)[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|$))|\.0+\b|\b0+(?=\.)
```

- `(?<=,|^)[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|$))` matches all parts that consist only of `[0.+-]` with at least a trailing zero. Limited by use of [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?<=,|^)` and `(?=0(?:,|$))`
- `|\.0+\b` or match a period followed by one or more zeros and a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).
- `|\b0+(?=\.)` or match a boundary followed by one or more zeros if a period is [ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Unquestioned cases like `0.`,`01`,`1.10` are not covered by this pattern yet. As a Java String:

```
"(?<=,|^)[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|$))|\\.0+\\b|\\b0+(?=\\.)"
```

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mT6uC6/1) or [Regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/wqme16) (click Java)

Comment: yes..some parts are not covered. we need to remove all zeros that are not required

Comment: sorry for replying late . ur case is failing for cases that have more than two zero before decimal like : -004.04 , this value remains same

Comment: @nKaushik I see, did little modification. There are [other cases, that my answer treats different](https://regex101.com/r/sA7oE6/1) to the [selected answer](https://regex101.com/r/aO6nM1/1).

Answer (score 1):

Using the list of numbers from your question, and some additional ones, the following regex replace will remove all leading and trailing zeros.

```
numbers.replaceAll("\\b0*([1-9]*[0-9]+)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?\\.?0*\\b", "$1$2");
```

with input:

> 2.0,3.00,-4.0,0.00,-0.00,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101,101.1010,0020.00

the result is:

> 2,3,-4,0,-0,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101,101.101,20

If you want to have decimals without the leading 0 then you can use the following.

```
numbers.replaceAll("\\b0*([0-9]+)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?\\.?0+\\b|0+(\\.[0-9]+?)0*\\b", "$1$2$3");
```

with input:

> 2.0,3.00,-4.0,0.00,-0.00,0.03,2.01,0.001,-0.03,101,101.1010,0020.00

the result is:

> 2,3,-4,0,-0,.03,2.01,.001,-.03,101,101.101,20

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 times replacement :

**first** use `\.0+(?=(,|$))` and replace with `""`

**then**  use `(?!(^|,))-0(?=(,|$))` and replace it with `"0"`

Comment: 0.001,-0.03 remain same

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to just use replace? example:

```
str.replaceAll("\.0+,|,0+(?=\.)", ",");
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS8hE3/4)

Answer (score 0):

`/(?!-)(?!0)[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*[1-9](?!0)|(?!-)(?!0)\.?[0-9]*[1-9](?!0)/g`