# Normalize decimal number regex

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that would normalize decimal number. When I say normalize I mean remove all leading zeros, and all trailing zeros after decimal point.

For example:

```
0.0 -> 0
1.230 -> 1.23
00123 -> 123
012.30400 -> 12.304
0102 --> 102"
```

So far i have came up with this

> (?<=,|^)(?:[0.+-]+(?=0(?:,|.\B|$))|0+(?=[1-9]))|.0+\b|\b0+(?=\d*.\b)|.\B|(?<=[1-9])0+(?=,|$)

the only problem for 0.1 it returns .1  otherwise it works

Comment: See a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35351336/3832970).

Comment: `[1-9]\d*(\.\d*[1-9])?` [nearly works](https://regex101.com/r/nSwepA/1), but fails for `0.x`.

Comment: "When I say normalize I mean remove all leading zeros" and "the only problem for 0.1 it returns .1" are contradictory. You *specifically* request to remove all leading zeros, and then point out as a problem that a leading zero is removed. One answer you got would cause this leading zero to be removed, the other would not, so this did in fact cause unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's one *entry* per line, try

```
^0*(\d+(?:\.(?:(?!0+$)\d)+)?)
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I9tZLF/2).

If you want to scan all for all, you could try

```
\b0*(\d+(?:\.(?:(?!0+\b)\d)+)?)
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/I9tZLF/1).

They both captures the number(s) to group 1.

If you want to remove everything but numbers, replace

```
^0*(\d+(?:\.(?:(?!0+$)\d)+)?).*$
```

with group 1.

[Check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/I9tZLF/3).

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternation should suffice:

```
^0+|(\.[0-9]+)0+$
```

Replacement would be capture group 1.