# Using RegEx how do I remove the trailing zeros and decimal also if needed

Tags: regex

I need to remove training Zero's on a number like:
9.2500 = 9.25
Thanks to a previous post by @Avinash Raj I found this:

```
^(\d+\.\d*?[1-9])0+$
```

Which works perfect for that application.  However, in some cases I have a number like 11.0000 and the above RegEx returns:

```
11.0
```

I need to return:

```
11
```

I'm not sure how to remove the decimal and zero when there is not one needed? I've spend some time trying to figure it out but I'm stumped.

Comment: The fact that you *can* do it with regex doesn't mean that you *should* ;) which programming language are you using ?

Comment: @alfasin I am using an automation application.  My only option to clean is regex. If could use java I'd be done.

Comment: Bob, you're asking for one regex that will do two different tasks (can you see why?). Another idea: run it once, and then run another regex to update numbers in the format: `n.0` to `n`

Comment: @BobTucker Try a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/T4qmV5/1) from [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35351336/3832970). It might suffice, or  it may do more than you need. Just select the alternatives you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d*?[1-9](?=0|\b))?)\.?0*$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/CMYH0q/1).

---

**explanation**

```
^         //Beginning of line
(         //Start collecting our group
\d+       //All digits before decimal
(?:       //START-Non collecting group
\.        //Decimal point
\d*?      //It should actually be [0-9]
[1-9]     //Last significant digit after decimal
(?=0|\b)  //Either should be followed by zero or END OF WORD
)?        //END-Non collecting group
          //The non-capturing group after decimal is optional
)         //End collecting our group
\.?       //Optional decimal (decimal collected if it wasn't used earlier)
0*        //All the remaining zeros no + as all digits might be significant that is no ending zero
$         //End of line.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
^(\d*[\d.]*?)\.?0*$
```

[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/txXFDX/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
^\d*\.[1-9]*([0]+)*$
```

Explanation

```
^  beginning of the term
\d*  digits from 0-9 those can be any number (can be 0 number or more)
\.   escaping the .
[1-9]* numbers from 1 to 9 (can be 0 number or more)
([0]+)  capturing all 0s in group1
$  end of the term
```

[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/SJ0teD/3)